# Wordpress menu items are not https links

Tags: wordpress

I want to use https instead of http on my wordpress site. The site is now running https and there is only one problem.
short facts of my past steps.

- Change the site and home url over the admin backend from http to https.
- Use Search and Replace Plugin and search http://'url' and change to https://'url' for all tables and fields except the guid.

Now the issue.
My site works over https with every page but the wordpress site generate for the menu only http links. There are 3 menues of the site and every menu has only http menus. Why? How does Wordpress generate these links?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try to use htaccess rules like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Comment: This would be the last solution if nothing works. I preference to solve this problem with wordpress itself instead with the apache server. Thank you for your solution.

Comment: Ok). But don't forget to mark my answer and upvote me when you end up using this solution (in order to guarantee that all your urls use https you will nee that) :)

Comment: I have set all my rep to the bounty. If I have more than 5 points, I up vote your answer ;)

Answer (score 4):

In case you never figured it out, I just did after encountering this issue lately and finding this question.

In current WP admin go to Settings > General.
Then simply add s after http.

[image]

Comment: Now whenever I go to "Edit" on a post, or anywhere else in my admin or site, every last URL starts with https.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the actions you have already taken, there are two possible cases (assuming your menus haven't been defined by a plugin):

1. Menu links are improperly hard-coded in template files.

   - If this is the case, you will need to find the relevant template files in your active theme (or create a child theme) and edit them. The proper way of defining hard-coded links in this case (if they must be hard-coded) is to use template tag functions such as [`site_url()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/site_url), which will automatically prefix links with the proper scheme and URL.
2. [Custom links](https://codex.wordpress.org/Appearance_Menus_Screen#Custom_Links) have been defined in menus, in the WP-Admin.

   - If this is the case, you can head to `WordPress Admin --> Appearance --> Menus` and edit the custom links in each of your menu items.

Comment: Thank you for the solution, but my menu consists only from wordpress pages. So the menu has no absolute links but only references of the wordpress pages which are handled by wordpress. In the backend itself the pages get displayed as https. This is the reason why I asked how wordpress generate the menu link. My theme has no hard coded links.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about using:-

https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-force-ssl/

This will force all of your internal links to use https://

It's the same as @SergeyAn answer but you don't have to edit the .htaccess file directly.